# For mobile apps, what's the best graphic design software I should use (Mac)?

Tags: software-recommendation, mac

I am an experienced programmer but new to graphic design.

I am making mobile apps for both iOS & Android, and I am wondering what graphic design tools/software I should use (in Mac) would be the best fit for a starter and for designing graphics for mobile apps?

Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: A visual example of a style would be more helpful in the future. Shopping questions based on today's market are not going to be relevant for long, as the software will continue to change. Recommending the feature sets that you would want, along with some software that implement them, will increase the amount of time that this question can help someone else.

Comment: There is no 'best' software. Use what works for you and your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the device you're designing for, you want something that can pitch out the image you're working on, straight to the device, so you can see what you're editing on the actual intended screen.

This sounds so logical you'd imagine it's easy to achieve and that someone had thoroughly setup a situation that did this live, easily.

Not true.

Let's deal with Apple first, because you should always design for this platform first. If you need this explained as to why this generalisation is true, you probably still believe in a benign Microsoft and the "virtues" of laissez-faire economics. So use an iPad or iPhone to begin with. Android devices compound the fiddliness of doing this.

The best rig is either iDisplay or AirDisplay. //both also work for Android

I prefer iDisplay but do use both, and at $20 a shot, it's not like you're breaking the bank to try each.  There's minor differences between them, both developers are responsive, but iDisplay is the little guy, and he's super cool with his email responses. So gets my nod:

iDisplay
http://www.getidisplay.com

Air Display is here:
http://www.avatron.com/apps/air-display/

// BOTH of these apps are designed for extending your display, so their benefits don't end with your testing of app interfaces dynamically. They're generally very helpful. iDisplay's touch screen responsiveness is (to me) a little better. So yes, you can operate your apps and draw on screen in Photoshop with these things. Amongst other benefits over things like Skala View etc.

Now for the hard bit. You need to get your work view over to the screen without borders and chrome etc.

Some apps are good at this, some are near impossible to get right.

Indesign is good at this. It has a full window preview mode that you can push out to the iDevice, as a duplicate of the open document, so you continue working in Indesign on the computer and see live updates on the iDevice screen.

I prefer a more powerful vector app for editing than Indesign, so I embed an Illustrator document into that Indesign document with live linking and then draw in Illustrator...hit a key combo that updates everything in Indesign and see it all update on the iPad/iPhone.

Adobe Bridge can do similarly, more directly, but is so prone to "losing its connection" that it's only stable for a few updates to the original file.

Photoshop is rather painful to work in for interface design, because it's not really suited to the job, and Fireworks, which was excellent for UI design is now a thing of the past.  BUT, Photoshop can also do second screen, full screen previews with a duplicate of the current document, so you get live updates on the device, without chrome and other nonsense obscuring your full screen viewing.

I've spent a lot of time testing these sorts of setups to do LIVE editing on the device, and this can be much more fiddly and unreliable than it should be, so please don't be shy about asking more questions. It may well be annoying to setup. But it's very much worth it for the ability to live edit and preview onscreen.

It would be completely remiss of me to not point out that this app does this "automagically", apparently:

http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/

I haven't tried it. But it's worth considering.

Sorry, while I'm handing out free advice, one more thing. If you're a competent programmer I think you should focus on becoming a great programmer. They're very rare. And in so doing, partner with a designer for design. Design might look like anyone can do it, that all you need do is learn the tools. But there's a magic ingredient to design, and that's an intuitive understanding of humanity's desires and opinions, feelings, sentiments and the zeitgeist of now. This is something that can't really be taught or learned. You either have sufficient empathy to be a designer and will push through learning the tools to express that, or you're a programmer.

If you're a programmer, and can communicate with a designer, that will ultimately be a 1+1=3 type of equation. You'll both benefit massively from the others talents, and be able to more deeply focus on your own talents and improving in that area.

So, in deeper answer to your question, the best design software for you to use is a designer.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed information. However, probably my question wasn't clear enough, I am actually wondering what graphic design "software" I should use. For example, should I use PhotoShop, illustraotr, iDraw... the graphic designed will be used in a mobile game app. That's what I really like to know. Thanks.

Comment: argh, that question is almost impossible to answer. Almost. We're in an interesting point in time when new drawing ideas are coming about, and if you're not already an Illustrator convert, and don't need the "rep" of being an Adobe user, I'd suggest drawing with Apple's Motion. For 2 reasons. 1 it's got very cool drawing tools, and 2. You can animate stuff, which is a HUGE boon for testing UI ideas. And it's only 49.99.

Comment: Further to this, using a modern Apple app will be a great insight into how UI can be. Adobe's software has (gently put) archaic user paradigms. I'd strongly suggest avoiding it if you can because just about every other app does it better.

Comment: Joe, please see new last sentence in my "answer". If you can express what you need, and how you want it, this is probably 10x faster for 10x better result. It looks like you're probably working in Corona, making some kind of game. That's a great place for designers to have fun. Designers have a lot of talent and time on their hands, it's just a matter of finding one that understands how difficult and time consuming programming is. Then you're balanced and set to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advise. I can understand your point (work with a designer). However, here is my situation. When I am trying to make some prototype of a game, I really need some fast development of some graphics regardless of its quality. I usually work with designers, but now I am thinking what if I can do it by myself first, would it save more time? And later, if the game is developed into a certain phase, I can start  to work with a designer to replace the graphics used in the game.

Comment: For example, like today I need to use a tiled map and I found some graphics online however I need to make some modifications on them first before I can use them programatically. I think I need to learn some basic graphic "handling".

Comment: On the other hand, for the prototype of the game I am trying to design, if I can design some basic components, I really think it's going to speed up a lot of things. Besides, I am actually thinking to learn some graphic designs too because I am kind of interested in it. So combined the work and my personal interest, I am just wondering what's the best software I should use when trying it out.

Comment: So far from the online research, my understanding is to use Photoshop for pixel art and Illustrator for vector graphics. I like your comment about Adobe software being archaic user paradigms. Probably it's the reason I asked the question here to see if I can find something else. I am totally new to this field, so it's going to matter a lot. I am kind of seeking a "jump start" or a right path before I start to commit the total energy into it. Besides, I am not really sure if I should go with pixel or vector type of editor and how about animation, etc. I try to figure out all these.

Comment: My comment about Apple's Motion is the one to look at closely, then. Motion is what's called a "Compositor", which is a really weird way of saying it can do much. Adobe's After Effects is a very similar application. Both allow you to do vector and pixel creation and editing, and animation. For games and apps this ability to make animations is priceless. You can test things out, and then render them out as sprite animation sequences and drop that into your project. But much more than that, the user paradigms of Motion are lightyears ahead of other software in the vector and pixel field.

Comment: And Apple's Motion has some really nice drawing tools, and some of the easiest to use pixel editing stuff in the market. And the user community is super supportive because they realise the space they're in, that they are ahead of the legacy software of Adobe. It's kind of a badge of honour amongst them to teach new comers in the best way possible. This in contrast to the arrogance of Adobe's forums and users who assume "professionalism" to be their sole right.

Comment: I took a look at that Sketch App, It's incredibly capable in vector, and outputs great bitmaps, so it's also something you should consider, and its user paradigms look as though they're distinctly inspired by the way Apple's Motion works. But ultimately Motion is the better choice, I believe. Just another quick tip about Apple Motion... every tutorial you see for Adobe's After Effects and most of what people do in Photoshop and Illustrator can be done in Motion. That's the kind of app it is.

Comment: JUST ONE MORE THING... Apple Motion's methodology and toolset follows (almost to the letter) the underlying APIs, classes, methods and functions of the drawing and image editing code base of OSX and iOS. So you'll inadvertently be learning Core Animation, Core Graphics and Core Image if you learn to use it. Which is a VERY cool feature of it that I think very few people are aware of because there's not much cross over between designers and programmers.

Comment: Apple Motion sounds a very good fit. It's weird that I never heard of it before. Glad I asked here and thanks for your advises. I will check it out.

Comment: It's an app few people would think of using for creating graphics because it's considered a "compositor", but that's a grotesque understatement of its abilities. And Adobe has a truly monopolistic hold on the design toolset conversation in the media. That's why you won't hear about a lot of alternatives, and will see much casual disregard for some of the (technically) far superior software choices.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Maybe I should put it this way. Apple Motion never came up in my search results when I was researching this topic. :) It's really interesting to know. I am checking it out. At the first glance, indeed it does not look like it's used for graphic design.

Comment: Yeah, that's because of that "compositor" thinking. When you see how the drawing tools act as a GUI for Core Grahpics you'll be amazed.

Comment: And since you're a programmer, I'd HIGHLY recommend this book: http://www.amazon.com/iOS-Core-Animation-Advanced-Techniques-ebook/dp/B00EHJCORC as it will show you how to animate in Core Animation, and concurrently, and incidentally teach you how much of animation works in software like After Effects or Motion. And you might find Core Animation is better than Corona ;)

Comment: Start here, for drawing in Motion: http://help.apple.com/motion/mac/5.0/en/motion/usermanual/index.html#chapter=20%26section=0

Comment: Without discrediting Illustrator and Photoshop users more than I need too (or want too), Motion and After Effects have such different usage paradigms that static image creators are kind of intimidated by them. But both of them have the drawing and image editing features of both Illustrator and Photoshop built in.. plus animation and compositing features. So they're kind of like the master class of design software. You can do all you'll need for game graphics with either After Effects or Motion, better and easier than doing it within the rigidities of Illustrator and Photoshop.

Comment: How do you know I am using Corona? (You mentioned in your answer, and I was kind of surprised) Although it's kind of off-topic, but here is my current feeling about using Corona. I originally was a C/C++ programmer and started to program for apps 6 months ago. Originally I was planning to learn to use Object-C of course, but then I bumped into Corona and I found it really speeds up the development time + one biggest advantage, cross-platform, so I am kind-of stick to it. Hence, when you said Core Animation is "better" than Corona, what are considered in the comparison?

Comment: And yes, this is slightly unconventional advice, most would tell you to start with the still image editing Illustrator or Photoshop, not to leapfrog to Motion. But I believe Motion is so much easier to learn and use that for the benefit of your production it's better to jump straight to it.

Comment: But there's nothing wrong with focusing on JUST iOS development. It's the leading app store by an order of magnitude. And will be for the foreseeable future. However if you're enjoying Corona there's no reason to leave.  But do take the time to read that book so you know where to go if you need to do more. And Core Animation (and Sprite Kit) are kind of super easy to use because of the APIs and the C-ness of Core Animation and the game loop and almost entity like systems of Sprite Kit.

Comment: If you're down the path with Corona, keep going. Completion is the only thing that matters. And Corona has sufficient performance, just focus on iOS first, and get finished. Worry about all that fragmentation on Android if the game is successful. Here's where and how to make all your game menus SING to the user: http://help.apple.com/motion/mac/5.0/en/motion/usermanual/index.html#chapter=17%26section=0

Comment: Aha, I see, yes, I have been using Corona heavily for the past 6 months, so I have asked a lot of question about Lua here. Yes, I can understand, sometimes game idea needs to be proven correct before putting more effort to make it better and expand it. When it comes to performance, I do believe XCode/Objective-C is the best. I hope there is one day I can move on to it.

Answer (score 2):

In the past I've mainly used a combination of **Photoshop** for actual pixel rendering and **Illustrator** for vector artwork (icons, bars, illustrations).

To preview artwork on my devices I've used **Liveview** and **Silkscreen.**

The pros to Liveview is that it's broadcasting a live view of a particular view port to your device from your desktop. The con is that it's broadcasting a live view of your desktop. I found myself moving windows a lot or screens savers triggering and needing to log back in.

The pros to Silkscreen was that it creates a new preview image every time you save your PSD. The cons to it was it didn't retain history of recent PSDs for quick reference so I found myself reloading files a lot.

There are a lot of interesting products coming out to assist designers with previewing artwork, though most of the time nothing is better than actually building the app. The recent Facebook Paper app was designed with a custom design tool built on top of Quartz Composer. ([Source](http://m.fastcodesign.com/3025932/facebook-develops-a-photoshop-for-interaction-design-and-its-free-for-anyone-to-use))

My best advice is to find some tools you're comfortable with and use those. Since you're a developer using something like Quartz Composer or even the open-source tool Facebook built on top of Quartz, Origami.